# Clustering / Matching Over Many Dimensions in R

Tags: r, sorting, cluster-analysis

I have a very large and complex data set with many observations of companies. Some of the observations of the companies are redundant and I need to make a key to map the redundant observations to a single one. However the only way to tell if they are actually representing the same company is through the similarity of a variety of variables. I think the appropriate approach is a kind of clustering based on a variety of conditions or perhaps even some kind of propensity score matching. Perhaps I just need flexible tools for making a complex kind of similarity matrix.

Unfortunately, I am not quite sure how to go about that in R. Most of the tools I've seen for clustering and categorizing seem to do so with either numerical distance or categorical data, but don't seem to allow multiple conditions or user specified conditions.

Below I've tried to create a smaller, public example of the kind of data I am working with and the result I am trying to produce. There are some conditions that must apply, for example, the location must be the same. There are some features that may associate one with another, for example var1 and var2. Then there are some features that may associate one with another, but they must not conflict, such as var3.

An additional layer of complexity is that the kind of association I am trying to use to map the redundant observation varies. For example, id1 and id2 are the same company redundantly entered into the data twice. In one place its name is "apples" and another "red apples". They share the same location, var1 value and var3 (after adjusting for formatting). Similarly ids 3, 5 and 6, are also really just one company, though much of the input for each is different. Some clusters would identify multiple observations, others would only have one. Ideally I would like to find a way to categorize or associate the observations based on several conditions, for example:
1. Test that the location is the same
2. Test whether var3 is different
3. Test whether the names is a substring of others
4. Test the edit distance of names
5. Test the similarity of var1 and var2 between observations

Anyways, hopefully there are better, more flexible tools for this than what I am finding or someone has experience with this kind of data work in R. Any and all suggestions and advice are much appreciated!

Data

```
id  name        location    var1    var2    var3
1   apples        US        1       abc     12345
2   red apples    US        1       NA      12-345
3   green apples  Mexico    2       def     235-92
4   bananas       Brazil    2       abc     NA
5   oranges       Mexico    2       NA      23592
6   green apple   Mexico    NA      def     NA
7   tangerines    Honduras  NA      abc     3498
8   mango         Honduras  1       NA      NA
9   strawberries  Honduras  NA      abcd    3498
10  strawberry    Honduras  NA      abc     3498
11  blueberry     Brazil    1       abcd    2348
12  blueberry     Brazil    3       abc     NA
13  blueberry     Mexico    NA      def     1859
14  bananas       Brazil    1       def     2348
15  blackberries  Honduras  NA      abc     NA
16  grapes        Mexico    6       qrs     NA
17  grapefruits   Brazil    1       NA      1379
18  grapefruit    Brazil    2       bcd     1379
19  mango         Brazil    3       efaq    NA
20  fuji apples   US        4       NA      189-35
```

Result

```
id  name        location    var1    var2    var3        Result
1   apples        US        1       abc     12345       1
2   red apples    US        1       NA      12-345      1
3   green apples  Mexico    2       def     235-92      3
4   bananas       Brazil    2       abc     NA          4
5   oranges       Mexico    2       NA      23592       3
6   green apple   Mexico    NA      def     NA          3
7   tangerines    Honduras  NA      abc     3498        7
8   mango         Honduras  1       NA      NA          8
9   strawberries  Honduras  NA      abcd    3498        7
10  strawberry    Honduras  NA      abc     3498        7
11  blueberry     Brazil    1       abcd    2348        11
12  blueberry     Brazil    3       abc     NA          11
13  blueberry     Mexico    NA      def     1859        13
14  bananas       Brazil    1       def     2348        11
15  blackberries  Honduras  NA      abc     NA          15
16  grapes        Mexico    6       qrs     NA          16
17  grapefruits   Brazil    1       NA      1379        17
18  grapefruit    Brazil    2       bcd     1379        17
19  mango         Brazil    3       efaq    NA          19
20  fuji apples   US        4       NA      189-35      20
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: What you have here is what we call a "hard" problem.  I think a way to create a numerical distance within each variable would be to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance.  You could then define some tolerance for total distance for matching. EDIT: I'll try to mock something up.

Comment: There are also packages that will help you to check the similarity to characters. It will allow you to conclude that 'apple' and 'red apple' are in same cluster.

Comment: @Adii_ There won't be any package that will match `"apples"` to `"red apples"` and not any of the other apples in there.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName You wanna bet? :)

Comment: @Adii_ Hmmm... Sure! I will be very impressed!

Comment: @iShouldUseAName It's 1 a.m. in Poland. I will be back in work tomorrow, so I can show you package I am thinking about. Generally speaking it take string and compare similarities of fixed numbers of characters from string. I will show you this tomorrow on example I'v done last week.

Comment: Hi @iShouldUseAName and @DaedalusBloom 
Following yesterday discussion, look on 2 packeges:
`library(kernlab)` and 'library(stringr)`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the ideas and discussion so far. I have some general ideas about the tests I would use, such as matching categoricals, edit distance (levenhstein) and substring searches (using grep). Assuming I have those rules/tests for categorization and a very, very large data set, its still unclear to me how I can cluster them flexibly enough for what i am trying to do. Are there clustering or categorizing tools that will 1) let me specify a variety of conditions, and 2) let the outcome be flexible such that some clusters have 1 item while others identify many?

Comment: What you have is a [record linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage) or deduplication problem. There exist algorithms for that. However, not for R anymore as far as I know as the [RecordLinkage](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html) package has been removed from CRAN.

Comment: How large is large? I ask as record linkage algorithms are often O(N^2).

Comment: @JanvanderLaan Yeah, to be clear I meant very big relative to my example provided here. I have about 50,000 records and about 50 variables I can use to associate them, though some variables could be used multiple times, for example the name may match based on edit distance or based on being substrings of one another. Also, thanks a bunch for explaining the record linkage description of the problem. I'll read up about it and see if I can find some useful techniques or tools.

Comment: If I were you I would come up with whatever series of conditions you want, assign a measure and then scale them to fit your personal logic about it.  One thing that concerns me about how you are approaching the problem is that you are expecting 100% accuracy based on your own personal logic/feeling about observations.  You won't get that.  It would require paraconsistent logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringdist)
getMatches <- function(df, tolerance=6){
  out <- integer(nrow(df))
  for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
    dists <- numeric(nrow(df))
    for(col in 1:ncol(df)){
      tempDist <- stringdist(df[row, col], df[ , col], method="lv")

      # WARNING: Matches NA perfectly.
      tempDist[is.na(tempDist)] <- 0
      dists <- dists + tempDist
    }
    dists[row] <- Inf

    min_dist <- min(dists)
    if(min_dist < tolerance){
      out[row] <- which.min(dists)
    }
    else{
      out[row] <- row
    }
  }
  return(out)
}

test$Result <- getMatches(test[, -1])
```

Where `test` is your data.  This probably definitely needs some refining and certainly needs some postprocessing.  This creates a column with the index of the closest match.  If it can't find a match within the given tolerance, it returns the index of itself.

EDIT: I will attempt some more later.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll tinker with this a bit and see if I can get something like this to work.